# Present participle Future

Tags: present-tense, present-participles

Is this sentence correct?
"I have all the documents and I should be filing it this week."
I know (I will be filing...) would work, but I was just wondering if the above sentence is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

"I have all the documents and I should be filing it this week" is grammatically acceptable.

Compared to "I will be filing," the use of "should" implies that the activity will likely get done, but it is possible that it will not get done or that it will be delayed. Therefore, the decision of which sentence to use will likely depend on how certain you are that the action will be done.